# How to Copy the table with Triggers and indexes in to another databases using single script for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have tried to use few syntax.

Create table b Like a;  -- This Do not work in Sql Server

Also have tried to understand this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21547/in-sql-server-how-do-i-generate-a-create-table-statement-for-a-given-table/317864#317864

Anyone have came accross similar issue?

Comment: Why don't you just use Generate Script in SSMS

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to copy (and  create ) a table from one database to another database including constraints, triggers, indexes and etc

I tried to create script through table and database itself, it creates table structure but do not copy triggers and all